# Subquery - Join

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm attempting to get a subquery in addition to a join statement that would display the FirstName and LastName of all customers who have had an order with an Item named 'Dress Shirt'. Then I have to report the results sorted by LastName in ascending order and then FirstName in descending order. This is what I have, but it keeps giving me 'NO ROWS SELECTED':

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM HW2G_CUSTOMER, HW2G_ORDER_ITEM
WHERE Item IN 
    (SELECT Item
     FROM HW2G_ORDER_ITEM
     WHERE Item = ‘DressShirt’)
ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName DESC;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you are doing a cross join between two tables.  The second is that the subquery in the IN is not returning any results.  'Dress Shirt" is probably not a valid value.  But, consider a query more like:

```
SELECT distinct FirstName, LastName
FROM HW2G_CUSTOMER c join
     HW2G_ORDER_ITEM i
     on c.customerID = i.customerID
WHERE i.Item = ‘Dress Shirt’
ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName DESC;
```

This won't fix the problem (which is the string "Dress Shirt"), but it is better syntax for moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want what you have right now, because you're doing a cross join. Take a look at this fiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30abb/5

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM HW2G_CUSTOMER WHERE CustomerId IN
    (SELECT CustomerId
     FROM HW2G_ORDER_ITEM
     WHERE Item = 'Dress Shirt')
ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- maybe a bit cleaner than @aqinas 's solution?
WITH wanted AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId
     FROM HW2G_ORDER_ITEM
     WHERE Item = 'Dress Shirt'
   )
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM HW2G_CUSTOMER cus
JOIN wanted wa ON wa.CustomerId = cus.CustomerId
ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName DESC
 ;
```